# Entity framework 5.0 transaction in buissnes logic layer

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In my businesses layer i have a reference to few dao objects. How to create a transaction to include all dao objects that perform database operations from the business layer. How to do it ?

I have one abstract class that is inherited by other  dao objects (perhaps one could use it?).

Comment: Post some code to demonstrate your current design

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest to use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   for transactions

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{

    // business logic

    scope.Complete();
}
```